# How to query a Mongoid Regexp Field?

Tags: ruby, regex, mongodb, mongoid

I want to create a regex field in my Mongoid document so that I can have a behavior something like this:

```
MagicalDoc.create(myregex: /abc\d+xyz/)

MagicalDoc.where(myregex: 'abc123xyz')
```

I'm not sure if this is possible and what kind of affect it would have. How can I achieve this sort of functionality?

**Update:** I've learned from the documentation that [Mongoid supports `Regexp` fields](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields) but it does not provide an example of how to query for them.

```
class MagicalDoc
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :myregex, type: Regexp
end
```

I would also accept a pure MongoDB answer. I can find a way to convert it to Mongoid syntax.

**Update:** Thanks to SuperAce99 for helping find this solution. Pass a string to a Mongoid `where` function and it will create a javascript function:

```
search_string = 'abc123xyz'
MagicalDoc.where(%Q{ return this.myregex.test("#{search_string}") })
```

The `%Q` is a Ruby method that helps to escape quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>`regexp` is not a valid [BSON type](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification), so you'll have to figure out how Mongoid represents it to devise a proper query.</s>

#### Query String using Regex

If you want to send MongoDB a regular expression and return documents MongoDB provides the [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query operator, which allows you to return documents where a string matches your regular expression.

#### Query Regex using String

If you want to sent Mongo a string and return all documents that have a regular expression that matches the provided string, you'll probably need the [`$where` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). This allows you to run a Javascript command on each document:

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { return (this.credits == this.debits) } } )
```

You can define a function which returns True when the provided string matches the Regex stored in the document. Obviously this can't use an Index because it has to execute code for every document in the collection. These queries will be very slow.

Comment: `Regexp` is the Ruby class that represents a regular expression. Mongoid converts it to the correct BSON type.

Comment: I think `$regex` is for using a regex in a query. It does not allow you to pass a string to find all the documents which have a regex that match your query string.

Comment: Sure, but what BSON type does it convert to? I suspect it's probably an object like `{type: "Regexp", value: "[a-z]+"}`, in which case you could query the `value` field like any other string.

What are you really trying to do? If you want to retrieve documents where a specific field matches your regular expression, the `$regex` operator should work for you.

Comment: It should convert it to a Regular Expression: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: Good find - I didn't see that in the spec.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39300/discussion-between-superace99-and-andrew)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've added a Mongoid specific solution to my post.